# How to connect to funambol server with my own ds client

Tags: android, funambol

I want to connect to funambol server to sync my data,from my ds client. I created a account for funambol server at webportal. Now if i try to connect to funambol server with first OMA DS package it is not retuning the response properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if i try to connect to funambol server with first OMA DS package it is not retuning the response properly.

You question isn't helping much. What do you mean by properly ?

Check the bottom of [this funambol page](https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/)

You can download the Java client SDK from there. This works on android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am implementing my own DS engine. when i try to connect to the funambol server (http://my.funambol.com") with the package one of DS protocol it only returns 135 bytes only containing headers.Not a valid response for package one in DS protocol. I want to know the correct funambol url to sent DS request.

Comment: https://help.forge.funambol.org/questions/answer2.html These are the setting to connect to funambol server.